# C++ star histogram

Tags: c++

So i need to make this :

[image]

I'm this far :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int x [3][4] = {{4, 3, 19, 3},
                      {15, 7, 11, 9},
                      {13, 5, 17, 1}}
                      ;


    cout <<"Elements Vertiba  Histogramma"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {


        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {


            cout << " ["   << i <<   "][" << j << "]  " << x [i][j] << endl;{
            }


        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...and?  You need to write more code. Do you need help with that? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: tip: `std::string(n,'*');` creates a string made out of `n` copies of `*`, thats basically all you need (unless this is an exercise about writing loops ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"*";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main() {

    int x [3][4] = {{4, 3, 19, 3},
                      {15, 7, 11, 9},
                      {13, 5, 17, 1}}
                      ;


    cout <<"Elements Vertiba  Histogramma"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {


        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {


            cout << " ["   << i <<   "][" << j << "]  " << x [i][j]<<"\t";
            print(x [i][j]);


        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While the code might solve the OP's problem, please provide an explanation of how and why the code works.

Comment: Inorder to get the desire output that you are mentioned you need to write it on the main or in a function and call the function .It just print the number of * according to the value present in the array .